# How to keep the objects created in `quarto::quarto_render()` in the current environment

Tags: r, quarto

**How to keep objects created in `quarto::quarto_render` in the current environment?**

- I need the same global values in multiple quarto-documents.
- I don't want to repeat those global values in each document.
- My current work-around is to store these global values in an r-script that i `source` at the top of each quarto-document.

Is it possible to `source` a quarto-document? So that the values created in the document are available to the document executing the `source`?

Comment: Have you looked into `knitr::knit_child()`?

Comment: From the point of view of reproducibility, your current work around is not bad either.